# DC JS : How to highlight rows in an aggregated data table on click, similar to a row chart?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I love the DC.JS library and have been trying to create a clickable aggregated table in DC.js with partial success. I want to highlight the rows on click event(multiple selections allowed) similar to the row chart or an ordinal bar chart in dc js. Like a row chart, when multiple selections are made, multiple table rows should be highlighted.

I am not able to select the row that I have clicked on, rather, my css selects the first row irrespective of which row I click. I tried to use 'this' keyword to select the current row that was clicked but to no avail.

Here's the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yashnigam/kvt9xnbs/83/

Here's my code for the click event that makes the css selection:

```
       marketTable.on("renderlet", function(chart){

        chart.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row').on('click',function(d){

            if(filterKeys.includes(d.key)){

             chart.select('tr.dc-table-row').datum(d.key).style('background-color','gray');
            }

        })

    });
```

Kindly share a way to highlight rows of data table on click, the same way it works on a row chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Hassan has the right idea. I would  suggest selecting the `tr`s rather than the `td`s, and instead of changing the classes on click (which wouldn't survive a redraw), apply the classes also during the `pretransition` event.

So:

```
tr.dc-table-row.sel-rows {
     background-color: lightblue;
}

marketTable.on('pretransition', function (table) {
    table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
      .on('click', /* ... */)
    table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filterKeys.indexOf(d.key) !== -1)
  });
```

[image: highlighted rows]
We apply the class based on whether the row's key is in the array. Straightforward and simple!

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/aofbu59y/12/)

#### using built-in filters

@vbernal pointed out that the list doesn't get reset when you click the reset link. To better integrate this, we can hook into the built-in filters that the table inherits from the base mixin (but doesn't ordinarily use):

```
  marketTable.on('pretransition', function (table) {
      table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
          .on('click',function(d){    
              let filters = table.filters().slice();
              if(filters.indexOf(d.key)===-1)
                  filters.push(d.key);
              else
                  filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
              table.replaceFilter([filters]);
              dc.redrawAll();
          });
      let filters = table.filters();
      table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
          .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
  });
```

Instead of setting `dimension.filter()` ourselves, we fetch the existing `table.filters()`, toggle as needed, and then set the filters using

```
table.replaceFilter([filters])
```

(Note the extra brackets.)

When the reset link is clicked, we reset the filter on the table rather than the crossfilter dimension. (It's always better to manipulate filters through the chart, because charts are not able to read the selection state from the crossfilter dimension.)

```
$('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
  marketTable.filter(null);
  dc.redrawAll();
});
```

[New version of fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/aofbu59y/62/)

Comment: This is Awesome and exactly what I wanted! Thanks Gordon.

Comment: We should probably add this feature to the library. I think I've answered this a couple of times. Of course it only works when there is a key per row (eg table is displaying a group).

Comment: Yes, I think adding click filtering and row highlighting features will enhance the aggregated data table. It'd be super cool!

Comment: Hello @Gordon, I'm making the code you put in JSFiddle and I was wondering if you can help me with something. When I click on any of the "buttons" reset, it resets only the numbers of the selected value. The table continues with the background-color as lightblue. Can you tell me how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @vbernal. Surprised I missed that. I added a new section above, with a better-integrated implementation.

Comment: Hi Gordon, after I went to examine it in more detail and realized that the image was reversed in relation to the first problem that I had reported to you. I posted here the solution I found:

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what was going wrong in your configuration. I added a pie chart to the demo and discovered some other problems with filtering. Fiddle updated above.

Answer (score 2):

In your onclick event, add (toggle) a class similar `.sel-rows` to clicked item (instead of change back color of it). Now in your css add this:

```
.sel-rows td{
     background-color: gray;
}
```

---

**Background color for table rows not work in some browsers.**

Answer (score 0):

As I said before, the changes that you (@Gordon) indicated worked, when I click the button, the table is redefined without any kind of color.

However, the problem was inversed, now the numbers remain the same.

I mixed it with the code you created and the solution I found was as follows:

```js
marketTable.on('pretransition', function(table) {
  table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
    .on('click', function(d) {
      let filters = table.filters().slice();
      if (filters.indexOf(d.key) === -1)
        filters.push(d.key);
      else
        filters = filters.filter(k => k != d.key);
      if (filters.length === 0)
        marketDim.filter(null);
      else
        marketDim.filterFunction(function(d) {
          return filters.indexOf(d) !== -1;
        })

      table.replaceFilter([filters]);
      dc.redrawAll();
    });
  let filters = table.filters();
  table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
    .classed('sel-rows', d => filters.indexOf(d.key) !== -1);
});
```

```js
$('#reset').on('click', function() {
  marketTable.filter(null);
  marketDim.filter(null)
  vendorDim.filter(null)
  CategoryDim.filter(null)

  dc.redrawAll();
});

$('#resetTable').on('click', function() {
  marketTable.filter(null);
  marketDim.filter(null)

  dc.redrawAll();
});
```

I don't know if it's the most elegant way to do this, I'm still a beginner in D3, DC and Crossfilter