# Dc.js v3 no pretransition event

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am referencing this question

[DC JS : How to highlight rows in an aggregated data table on click, similar to a row chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373150/dc-js-how-to-highlight-rows-in-an-aggregated-data-table-on-click-similar-to-a)

```
nasdaqTable.on('pretransition', function (table) {
    table.selectAll('td.dc-table-column')
      .on('click', /* ... */)
    table.selectAll('tr.dc-table-row')
        .classed('sel-rows', d => filterKeys.indexOf(d.key) !== -1)
  });
```

However, i ran into an exception

```
d3.js:754 Uncaught (in promise) Error: unknown type: pretransition
    at d3.js:754
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseTypenames (d3.js:751)
    at Dispatch.on (d3.js:763)
    at Object._table.on (datatable.js:116)
    at stock.js:305
```

I am sure the pretransition event is in dc.js. I am using dc.js v3.0.5 and d3v5.

Comment: From your stack trace, it looks like you are using [dc.datatables.js](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.datatables.js), not `dc.dataTable`. Again, if you want to use dc.datatables.js, you need to look for help on how to highlight rows using DataTables, not `dc.dataTable`. dc.datatables.js strives to be a drop-in replacement for `dc.dataTable`, but I doubt that any customizations which work on `dc.dataTable` will work with dc.datatables since the DOM structure is completely different (different classes, different use of tbody/tr/td, etc etc.)

Comment: Take dc.js out of your search terms for this one. Searching for "select rows datatables.js" I get [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html) which looks like what you want.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot! Gordon. Will try out those! Thanks once again!

Comment: @Gordon Do you mind if i ask you another question. I was debugging my script and i realise this is not working for me due to the d3.csv calls being async. As such, using a document.ready event would not be possible since it will attach the click event to an empty element. How do i ensure that the script is run before i run any further scripts?

Comment: You'll want to attach any events after each time the table is drawn. So you could wait for `table.on('renderlet'...` instead of `$.ready`. You might also want to take a look at [dc-tableview](https://github.com/karenpommeroy/dc-tableview). I just learned about it and it looks more fully featured than dc.datatables.js

Comment: @Gordon OMG this is soooo helpful. I would love to accept this as an answer honestly. Cannot thank you enough for your quick replies as well