# Text-Widget Applied to an aggregated data table

Tags: dc.js

Utilizing the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373150/dc-js-how-to-highlight-rows-in-an-aggregated-data-table-on-click-similar-to-a) provided by Gordon, I've successfully created a selectable table that contains aggregated data. Now I would like to filter the data with the [text-filter-widget](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web-src/examples/text-filter-widget.html).

I understand that the filter needs an array to work properly. What I am trying to understand is how might one be able to update the table rows when the table filters are looking at a group?

Comment: Could you explain further? The example should work pretty much the same if the table is looking at a group rather than a dimension. Crossfilter needs an array, but I don’t think how the text filter needs an array, unless I’m missing something. It’s just a regular filter that does substring matching.

Comment: Still pretty new to this but wanted to try and create my own fiddle with your code. Seems to me that I can either select d3 or jquery not both.  Can you give advice on how I might get this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coal_canary/wu3cL0be/5/) working

Comment: You can add jQuery as another resource. I just typed jquery and clicked (+) and it worked. Will answer dc question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text filter widget is different from a chart in that it takes a dimension to filter on.

We also need to declare a second market dimension [so that it will filter the table](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters).

Thus

```
var marketDim, marketDim2;
// ...
marketDim = facts.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.Location;
});
marketDim2 = facts.dimension(function(d) {
  return d.Location;
});
// ...
search
  .dimension(marketDim2);
```

[image: screenshot]

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/d91Lxmuw/1/).